# Course Timer overloading server

Tags: mysql, ajax, timer

My client has a few online course sites that include a simple timer that records student time on the course. For example it will countdown from 40 hours. Students are required to log 40+ hours. The value is saved to the mysql database every second or about every 10 seconds I believe. This simple action seems to be overloading the cloudlinux server that I have.

The timer uses a javascript / ajax (WP Heartbeat) backend to display and record the values to the database. The file being called is typically admin-ajax.php

Is there a more efficient way this should be setup? My developer insists this is the best way. Do I just add more server resources (aka $$$) to these sites? I've been told to disable heartbeat or adjust the frequency but my site relies on this function to log student time.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you wouldn't update the DB so often for every user.

You would let the client side show how the counter updates every second (or every few seconds), but you will update the DB:

- Every 1 minute (for example)
- On main page actions, like 'Close'/'Quit'/... that you want to capture

This way your DB data is not accurate to the second, but why would you need that to track 40 hours? Would users really say "*I did my 40 hours but it only shows 39 hours and 59 minutes*"?

Comment: I think you make some really good points thank you. Do you have any other suggestions on how to lessen server load? With multiple users on the site it tends to overload quickly. @Galz

Comment: @kevllar Another potion is server side layer that gets all those heartbeats from the client, aggregates them into bulks and saves them in bulk to the DB every minute (or every X updates that got accumulated)

Comment: is that "layer" software that exists or web custom code that needs to be written? Can you point to a GitHub project or example?

Comment: @kevllar - I don't know of anything that does this out of the box, but there must be libraries that can help... Not sure I can point you to them though. Leave the question open for others to see this conversation - I am sure some ppl here have experience with this (I am a DB guy :)